# what does the "1" in this Typescript code mean?

Tags: typescript

Could someone explain to me what the 1 here in this TS code does?

```
    decryptPassPhrase() {
    this.$encrypt.setPrivateKey(privateKey);
    this.decryptedPassPhrase = this.$encrypt.decrypt(this.encryptedPassPhrase);
1
        if (Object.is(this.textToConvert, null)) {
      console.error("decryption failed");
        }
  }
```

Comment: It's a typo, somebody's finger slipped and they didn't notice.

Comment: it compiles with no errors though

Comment: @J.F. it's valid JS/TS - it's a literal which assigned to nowhere, literally a no-op.

Comment: Yes, that's true, My apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1` is a [*numeric literal*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-literals-numeric-literals). It represents the number 1.

Since it is not assigned to a variable, not returned, not passed as an argument, and has no side-effect, it will have no effect on either the result or the behavior of the program.

In other words, it literally does nothing.